# How to have Selection hyperlink open in new tab

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I have the following XML for my MTurk answer selection:

```
    <AnswerSpecification>
        <SelectionAnswer>
            <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
            <Selections>
                <Selection>
                    <SelectionIdentifier>0</SelectionIdentifier>
                    <Text>No URL exists</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                    <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
                    <Text>http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2271332/</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                    <SelectionIdentifier>2</SelectionIdentifier>
                    <Text>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460987/</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                    <SelectionIdentifier>3</SelectionIdentifier>
                    <Text>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1450653/</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                    <SelectionIdentifier>4</SelectionIdentifier>
                    <Text>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1438289/</Text>
                </Selection>
            </Selections>
        </SelectionAnswer>
    </AnswerSpecification>
```

However, whenever a user clicks one of the links, it goes **away** from the test and goes to that link. Is there a way to add something like `target="_blank"` to the Selection on MTurk?

Comment: I think you should be able to obtain this using [formatted content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_FormattedContentXHTMLArticle.html) that includes your own `<a>` tag with a specified target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using FormattedContent for your task:

```
<Selection>
  <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
  <FormattedContent><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2271332/" target="_blank">http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2271332/</a>]]></FormattedContent>
</Selection>
```

You can get more details on the QuestionForm data structure, including useful examples, here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html